# Как ограничить rotation объекта в three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

Я загрузил и вывел объект, подключил управление с помощью trackballcontrols.

Мне нужно, что бы при манипуляциях мышкой объект крутился только по оси Х, а все остальные оси, зум, перенос объекта с помощью пкм были отключены.

Как это сделать? Возможно в trackballcontrols можно как то поменять методы для этого.
Спасибо!

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera );

controls.rotateSpeed = 10;
controls.noZoom = true;
controls.noPan = true;
```

Comment: такое легче всего руками провернуть без всяких библиотек

Comment: был бы благодарен, если бы вы описали приблизительную логику.

объект нужно с помощью мышки вращать по оси Х

Answer (score 2):

Нашел решение, легко кастомизируется.

https://jsfiddle.net/MadLittleMods/n6u6asza/

```
var isDragging = false;
```

var previousMousePosition = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
};
$(renderer.domElement).on('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDragging = true;
})
.on('mousemove', function(e) {
    //console.log(e);
    var deltaMove = {
        x: e.offsetX-previousMousePosition.x,
        y: e.offsetY-previousMousePosition.y
    };

```
if(isDragging) {

    var deltaRotationQuaternion = new three.Quaternion()
        .setFromEuler(new three.Euler(
            toRadians(deltaMove.y * 0),
            toRadians(deltaMove.x * 1),
            0,
            'XYZ'
        ));

    cube.quaternion.multiplyQuaternions(deltaRotationQuaternion, cube.quaternion);
}

previousMousePosition = {
    x: e.offsetX,
    y: e.offsetY
};});


$(document).on('mouseup', function(e) {
isDragging = false;});
```